# Multiple data-toggles in jade page

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I want to make a little page for data exchange in text or image form.
I want to set up now a mvc-based architecture for my case.

It works pretty well but now i have an issue. Is it possible to make a tooltip visible, while the data-toggle inside a link is set to 'dropdown'?

For a better example here some jade code:

```
ul
  li
    a(title='', data-toggle='tooltip', data-placement='left', data-original-title='video')
      i.glyphicon.glyphicon-camera
  li
    a(title='', data-toggle='tooltip', data-placement='bottom', data-original-title='picture')
      i.glyphicon.glyphicon-picture
  li.dropdown
    a(title='', data-toggle='dropdown', data-hover='tooltip', data-placement='right', data-original-title='category')
      i.glyphicon.glyphicon-menu-hamburger
    ul.dropdown-menu
      li
        a(href="#")
        | Here should be a dropdown with some possible choices (checkboxes)
      li
        ...
```

In addition i have this line in the related angular controller:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
  $("[data-toggle=tooltip]").tooltip();
});
```

But i want to show a tooltip [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MU3k.png)

Now how can i show a tooltip and a dropdown menu with entries (*btw from a json file loaded with jquery*) at the same time?
What am i doing wrong?
Could it be a problem with css?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: okay. i got it it was something mixed up in my css. i had to change the code in the angular controller also. thanks